# Using moment for time to calculate differnce

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two date:

```
const a = moment(start)
const b = moment(end)
```

where for example:  `a  "2022-03-22T09:00:00.000Z"  b  "2022-03-22T09:30:00.000Z"`

Now I'm interested to calculate only difference about time.

So for example if I do `moment.duration(b.diff(a)))` i obtain PM30

But what I would to obtain is the difference like:

```
`a  "2022-03-22T09:00:00.000Z"  b  "2022-03-22T09:30:00.000Z"`   => b - a = 0.5
`a  "2022-03-22T09:00:00.000Z"  b  "2022-03-22T10:30:00.000Z"`   => b - a = 1.5
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get in hours add `.asHours()`

```js
var a = moment('2022-03-22T09:00:00.000Z');//now
var b = moment('2022-03-22T10:30:00.000Z');

console.log(moment.duration(b.diff(a)).asHours());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily computed using standard JavaScript Dates without incurring the additional overhead in case that's an option to you:

```js
const SEC = 1000, MIN = SEC * 60, HOUR = MIN * 60, DAY = HOUR * 24;
const a = new Date("2022-03-22T09:00:00.000Z");
const b = new Date("2022-03-22T09:30:00.000Z");
const diff = b - a;

console.log("Time difference is:\n" +
    `${diff} milliseconds or\n` +
    `${diff / SEC} seconds or\n` +
    `${diff / MIN} minutes or\n` +
    `${diff / HOUR} hours or\n` +
    `${diff / DAY} days`);
```